# Cakephp 2 form does not post data after adding text area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple cake php app. When I am trying to edit my data in a form everything is fine. unless  I add text area to my form. When I add text are the form does not post data and it refresh itself. It is like noting happens at all!!
I disabled all my javascript file but It did not help I also put no validate rule but it did not work either.
Here is my controller function:

```
public function edit($id = null) 
    {

        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid audit'));
        }

        $audit = $this->CreditAudit->findById($id);
        if (!$audit) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid audit'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->CreditAudit->id = $id;
            if ($this->CreditAudit->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your audit has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your audit.'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $audit;
        }
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('CreditAudit');
?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Product Purchase Plan'); ?></legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Credit Report Audit: Tri-Merge Credit Audit</td>
<td>Amt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
1 Payment of $50.00
<?php
    //echo $this->Form->checkbox('Payment', array('hiddenField' => false));
?>
</td>
<td>$50</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
 <legend><?php echo ('Contact Information'); ?></legend>
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('cell',array('label'=>'Cell phone # (Numbers only!)'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('birthday',array('label'=>'Birthday (MM/DD/YYYY)'));
    echo $this->Form->input('SSN',array('label'=>'SSN (Numbers only!)'));
    echo $this->Form->input('refferal',array('label'=>'Who reffered you to us?'));
    echo $this->Form->input('notes',array('rows' => '3','name'=>'editor1','class'=>'ckeditor','type' => 'textarea','escape' => 'false','novalidate' => 'true'));
?></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo 'Billing Address'; ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('street_adress_1');
    echo $this->Form->input('street_adress_2');
    echo $this->Form->input('city');
    echo $this->Form->input('state');
    echo $this->Form->input('postal_code',array('label'=>'Postal Code (Numbers only!)'));
?></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Credit Card Information'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('card_type',array('options'=>array('Visa'=>'Visa','Master card'=>'Master Card'),'empty'=>'Please select card type'));
    echo $this->Form->input('card_number');
    echo $this->Form->input('expiration_year',array('options'=>array('2013'=>'2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022','2023','2024','2025'),'empty'=>'Choose one'));
    echo $this->Form->input('expiration_month',array('options'=>array('01'=>'01','02'=>'02','03'=>'03','04'=>'04','05'=>'05','06'=>'06','07'=>'07','08'=>'08','09'=>'09','10'=>'10','11'=>'11','12'=>'12'),'empty'=>'Choose one'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cvc');

?></fieldset>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->end('Update');
?>
```

Comment: Does everything get posted except the text in the textarea or nothing gets posted at all?

Comment: Are you using Ckeditor?